# Template Argument Deduction C++

Tags: c++, templates

I tried to compile following lines of code and it fails:

```
template <typename T>
struct InputBlockParameterType {
    typedef T type;
};

template <typename T, template <typename> class BlockTypeTrait>
struct BlockParameterImpl {
    typedef typename BlockTypeTrait<T>::type type;
};

template <typename T>
struct InputBlockParameter {
    typedef typename BlockParameterImpl<T, InputBlockParameterType>::type type;
};


struct Functor {
    template <typename T>
    bool operator()(typename InputBlockParameter<T>::type p) {
        return true;
    }
};

int main() {
    InputBlockParameter<double>::type arg = 0.0;

    Functor f;
    f(arg);

    return 0;
}
```

The error is (MSVC 2013):

```
1>main.cpp(31): error C2783: 'bool Functor::operator ()(InputBlockParameter<T>::type)' : could not deduce template argument for 'T'
1>          main.cpp(21) : see declaration of 'Functor::operator ()'
```

If I change the functor to

```
struct Functor {
    template <typename T>
    bool operator()(T p) {
        return true;
    }
};
```

Everything compiles fine as expected.

Why is the first version of the code not compiling? Is it somewhere defined in the standard?

Comment: Everything to the left of `::` is a non-deduced context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deduction only works in a deduced context.

Which is useless: X only works when X works.  I could quote the standard, but it just says "yep, that don't work" in harder to read prose.

The best way to think about it is that the compiler just does pattern matching.  It does not, however, search or try to invert any type mappings you write.

`foo<T>::type` could do a Turing complete computation (up to compiler limits) to go from `T` to `type`: so the standard declares the use of `T` there to be a non-deduced context, even if the `foo` type map seems easy to invert to you.  Inverting arbitrary functions is not a practical thing to ask compilers to do, even if we already ask them to be Turing complete in order to compile C++.

The compiler will not convert (other than to base and cv stripping and argument decay), or invert a type mapping during template type deduction.  It just pattern matches the arguments.

It will follow type maps for SFINAE purposes, but that is theoretically much easier.

If you can write the inverse map yourself, you can use a mixture of SFINAE and default parameters and template class specialization and forwarding to get the effect you probably want.